# Styleable cannot be resolved

Tags: android, xml, android-custom-view, declare-styleable, styleable

Here is the code I am using:

```
public ASSwitch(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    TypedArray sharedTypedArray = context.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(
            attrs,
            R.styleable.ASSwitch,
            0, 0);

       try {
           onText = sharedTypedArray.getText(R.styleable.ASSwtich_onText, null);

       } finally {
           sharedTypedArray.recycle();
       }
}
```

Here is the attrs.xml file (added to values folder):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="ASSwitch">
        <attr name="onText" format="string" />
        <attr name="offText" format="string" />
        <attr name="onState" format="boolean" />
        <attr name="toogleDrawable" format="string" />
        <attr name="frameDrawable" format="string" />
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

The answers in these questions couldn't fix the problem. Please don't consider my question as duplicate.

- [Android Hello, Gallery tutorial -- "R.styleable cannot be resolved"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1717489/android-hello-gallery-tutorial-r-styleable-cannot-be-resolved)
- [Android: How to Declare Styleable in R.java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11541132/android-how-to-declare-styleable-in-r-java)
- [R.styleable can not be resolved, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6675403/r-styleable-can-not-be-resolved-why)
- [R.styleable cannot be resolved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4283455/r-styleable-cannot-be-resolved)

---

**Update**: It seems that I was importing the wrong R class. It shall be the application's `R` class not `android.R`.

Answer (score 5):

Check your imports:

- Wrong: `Android.R`
- Correct: `com.example.yourproject.R`

I had the same error when made this customized view. Maybe when follow the guiding step, the helper tool automatically inserts this wrong import.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that I was importing the wrong R class. It shall be the application's R class not android.R

Comment: If this is the answer, then please accept your own answer to help future visitors. That's how Stack Overflow works. See [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/173448).